# Accessing Bitset present inside a struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, bitset

I have a structure that looks like this :

```
struct bf_t {
bitset<250000> h0;
};
```

I want to know how to allocate memory for this struct and how to access h0 in my main() .

I tried doing this:

```
bf_t *b;
b->h0.set(1); 

error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer

bf_t *b ;
b.h0.set(1); 

error: request for member ‘h0’ in ‘b’, which is of non-class type ‘long long int’
```

Comment: The first one should have worked, all your missing there is actually _allocating_ the memory for the structure. But why don't you just declare it as a normal (non-pointer) variable?

Comment: It is defined like this in my project specs..

Answer (score 0):

When you declare pointers like this `bf_t *b;` you have to assign to them before you use them. You probably want to create a new bf_t on the heap like this: `b = new bf_t();`. Then you can use `->` to access its members.

Comment: That is not really relevant here though.

Comment: allocate/define not declare

Comment: @Tim : I tried , but I get the same error . error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer

Answer (score 0):

The error message and your code mismatch. However, it’s much easier – you don’t need pointers at all:

```
bf_t b;
b.h0.set(1);
```

Comment: According to the specs for my project, I should be using a pointer .